# how to get data of maximum date in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have three tables..

```
SEEKER
seeker_nic--- username---request_fulfilled
111-----------ali--------YES
222-----------bilal------YES
```

second table is

```
DONOR
donor_nic---username----area
999----------Fahad-------UK
555----------SAJAD------USA
777---------HAMZA-------PK
```

third table is

```
STATUS
status-id---seeker_nic---donor_nic--requestfulfilled_by----request_fulfilled_date 
1 -------------111-------999---------- Fahad-------------2012/04/09
2 -------------111-------555---------- SAJAD-------------2012/05/15
3--------------222------777-----------HAMZA--------------2012/07/20
```

now i want this result for SEEKER (111) with latest data..

```
seeker_nic---username--- request_fulfilled---requestfulfilled_by----area---request_fulfilled_date
111-----------ali--------YES-----------------SAJAD-----------------USA--------2012/05/15
```

i am trying this query, this query shows rite seeker_nic, and requestfulfilled_date, but it shows wrong donor-nic, area and requestfulfilled_by...

```
SELECT seeker.seeker_nic, donor.donor_nic, donor.area, 
status.requestfulfilled_b , max( status.`request_fulfilled_date` ) AS request_fulfilled_date
FROM seeker
JOIN STATUS ON seeker.seeker_nic = status.seeker_nic
JOIN DONOR ON status.donor_nic = donor.donor_nic
WHERE seeker.username = '$uname'
GROUP BY status.`seeker_nic`
```

i am getting ans like this....

```
seeker_nic---username--- request_fulfilled---requestfulfilled_by--------area--------request_fulfilled_date
111-----------ali---------------YES-----------------HAMZA--------------PK------------2012/05/15
```

plz help me.. :(

Comment: *"i am trying this query,"* - you have not put your query to your question which would be good to know.

Comment: i just forgot .. i have added query now...

Comment: Whats about the common `ORDER BY date_column DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: well its again same problem.. it cam find rite date and rite seeker_nic,, but it show requestfulfilled_by and area of other user :( plz help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT seeker.seeker_nic, donor.donor_nic, donor.area, status.requestfulfilled_by, status.request_fulfilled_date
FROM seeker
JOIN (
  SELECT seeker_nic, max(request_fulfilled_date) as last_date
  FROM status
  GROUP BY seeker_nic
) x ON x.seeker_nic = seeker.seeker_nic
JOIN STATUS 
  ON x.seeker_nic = status.seeker_nic
  AND x.last_date = status.request_fulfilled_date
JOIN DONOR 
  ON status.donor_nic = donor.donor_nic
WHERE seeker.username = '$uname'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to select latest date for one particular user, you do not need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    status.request_fulfilled_date, # status.requestfulfilled_by,
    seeker.seeker_nic, seeker.username, seeker.request_fulfilled,
    donor.donor_nic, donor.username, donor.area 
FROM      status
LEFT JOIN seeker ON status.seeker_nic = seeker.seeker_nic
LEFT JOIN donor  ON status.donoc_nic  = donor.donor_nic
WHERE seeker.username = 'ali'
ORDER BY status.request_fulfilled_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this query also works according to my requirements... thnx @Salman A :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.seeker_nic, y.username, y.request_fulfilled,
       x.requestfulfilled_by, z.area, x.request_fulfilled_date
FROM status x, seeker y, donor z
WHERE x.seeker_nic=y.seeker_nic AND y.seeker_nic=111 AND z.donor_nic=x.donor_nic;
```